# Changing menu paths for existing nodes in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, uri, routes

So I have created around 100 articles of a specific content type and provided all of them a menu path under a specific menu.

Now the requirement is to alter these menu paths and give these nodes a new menu path under another menu. The longer and obvious way to go about doing this is to edit each of these content types manually and then edit the menu path to edit and point it to the new menu. This is a painstaking procedure that shall consume time. I am sure there are alternatives such as a Drupal module that let's you mass alter menu paths for a specific content type?

Alternately, is there a way for me to get into the drupal database and find out where these menu paths for a specific node/content type are stored? And I can simply execute a query that goes in and changes that?

Thanks!

Comment: Your approval rate is kind of low. Consider accepting the best answers on your posts and upvoting the ones you deem acceptable so the help you received can help others. Thanks friend.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. You can configure it to create paths automatically with a given pattern for individual content types. It also has options to bulk delete and update existing paths.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you can just use Pathauto module for this.
2. [Refer Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto)
3. Rename the URL pattern and use the Bulk update function to regenerate all aliases.
4. You can also do this through the content overview screen (/admin/content) by filtering out the content type and then select all and choose "Update URL alias" from the drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out these modules:

D6 - [Menu Editor](http://drupal.org/project/menu_editor) - provides a better interface to make it easier to edit the paths in case you have to do it manually.

D6/D7 - [Menu Import](http://drupal.org/project/menu_import)  - I believe you can use this by writing up a properly formatted/syntax text file, with all of your new menu items, and import it into Drupal. If you are handy with keyboard and copy/paste regex or whatever, this might be faster.

Comment: thanks @DavidCsonka, Menu_editor does not seem to have a Drupal 7 version of it's module. Does it make any sense to give the version 6 iteration a chance anyways ? thanks!

Comment: Probably only if you don't mind using Drupal 6 core.